# Do i need to calculate the frequency of terms in the whole data or for each document for tf-idf?

Tags: nlp

Do i need to calculate the frequency of terms in the whole data or for each document for tf-idf ?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the equation for tf-idf and the steps how they are computed.

**tf**
you basically have to tokenize all the terms you have in the dataset and vectorize them for each document. = ]

**idf**
apply idf term for each *token* not for each document!